# Prove the following integral is asymptotically zero

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

I have to solve the following exercise. I would appreciate to get a hint for it. Suppose $(\Omega, \mathcal{F}, \mu)$ be a measure space. Let $f$ be an integrable function. Show 
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_{\{w:|f(w)|>n\}}|f|d\mu=0.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$|f|1\{|f|>n\}\le |f|\in L^1.$$

Thus,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\int|f|1\{|f|>n\}d\mu=\int \lim_{n\to\infty}|f|1\{|f|>n\}d\mu.$$

Comment: @Cupitor The theorem that is hidden in between the lines of this answer is called Dominated Convergence Theorem. Check its formulation and think of cases when it cannot be applied!